# Function fails to return a value

Tags: function, sass

I am using a sass snippet from [this website](http://hmphry.com/useful-sass-mixins) to create color stacks.

```
$color-stack:
(group: foo, id: normal, color: #e67835),
(group: foo, id: pale, color: #f8a878),
(group: foo, id: dark, color: #ad490c),
(group: bar, id: normal, color: #426682);

// Color  Function
@function color($group, $shade:normal, $transparency:1){
  @each $color in $color-stack{
    $c-group: map-get($color, group);
    $c-shade: map-get($color, id);
    @if($group == map-get($color, group) and $shade == map-get($color, id)){
      @return rgba(map-get($color, color), $transparency);
    }
  }
}
```

Later in my code I want to use `@each` to give some elements different colors depending on their parent class

```
@each $category in foo, bar {
    .cat-#{$category} {
        .some-class {
            background-color: color(#{$category}, pale);
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect this to compile to:

```
.cat-foo .some-class {
    background-color: #f8a878; //the value of foo pale on the $color-stack map
}
```

Instead it throws and error: `Function color did not return a value`

If I replace the `#{$category}` with the string `foo` it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are looking for a group with the value `bar` and with an id of `pale`. This does not exist in your map so the function does not return a value.

Add that and it works.

```
$color-stack:
(group: foo, id: normal, color: #e67835),
(group: foo, id: pale, color: #f8a878),
(group: foo, id: dark, color: #ad490c),
(group: bar, id: normal, color: #426682),
(group: bar, id: pale, color: #000);
```

Comment: that worked, thanks!